# Entropy maximizing distribution when power constraint exists for one random variable

Tags: probability, optimization, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Suppose I have a random vector $\bar{X}=[X_{1},X_{2}, X_{3}]$. 
X1,X2 and X3 can take values from the alphabet {0,1,2,3} . (This can be even generalized to a finite set of cardinality N). I don't have any information on the probability distribution of these random variables.

If X is random variable then its entropy is:

$H(X) = -\displaystyle\sum_{x} p(x)\log p(x).$

Similarly, I understand that we have definitions for joint entropy for the random vector $\bar{X}=[X_{1},X_{2}, X_{3}]$.

I understand that  If no constraints exist the entropy maximizing distribution is uniform distribution. So here the joint pdf will be uniform pdf when no constraints exist.

My questions:

1. What if I have a constraint on $X_{3}$ such that $E[{X_{3}}^{2}] <\alpha$
2. What if I have a constraint on $X_{2}$ and $X_{3}$ such that $E[{X_{2}}^{2}] +E[{X_{3}}^{2}]<\alpha$

How will we go about finding the entropy maximising distributions in this case? Can anyone give some details.

Thanks.

Comment: read into convex optimization

Comment: Related (similar) question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949210/find-probability-distribution-joint-pdf-that-satisfy-constraints

Comment: It seems that max entropy is reached when all your random variable are mutually independent. In my opinion, it boils down to your question 1 with only one variable X.

Comment: It would be great if that can be supported mathematically.